# Splitting row value into specific columns based on the value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table like this which is actually manages impediments in VSTS

```
Team Name   Item ID    Score   Score Label
-------------------------------------------
Team1         1          2     Green
Team1         2          0     Red
Team1         3          1     Amber
Team1         4          2     Green
Team1         5          0     Red
Team2         6          1     Amber
Team2         7          0     Red
Team3         8          2     Green
```

But I need to present this in a different way like this

```
Team Name   Item ID    Score   Green    Amber     Red
------------------------------------------------------
Team1         1          2       1       0         0
Team1         2          0       0       0         1
Team1         3          1       0       1         0
Team1         4          2       1       0         0
Team1         5          0       0       0         1
Team2         6          1       0       1         0
Team2         7          0       0       0         1
Team3         8          2       1       0         0
```

I believe SQL pivoting is the best way. But I'm not an expert in pivot. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017 there are docs here with examples - try adapting one of those and post some updates if you get stuck

Comment: "different way" seems like some dancing figures :)

Answer (score 2):

A case expression is probably the quickest solution:

```
    SELECT Team Name, Item ID, Score
    , case when Score Label = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end as 'Green'
    , case when Score Label = 'Amber' then 1 else 0 end as 'Amber'
    , case when Score Label = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end as 'Red'
    from Table
```